# How to make RAY calculate multiple trials in parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, ray

My code is:

```
config = {
    "num_workers" : 19,
    #"num_gpus": 1,
    "gamma" : tune.grid_search([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]),       
    "lr" : tune.grid_search([1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001])}
```

and:

```
analysis = tune.run(config=config)
```

When I run this, I have:

```
Number of trials: 23/42 (22 PENDING, 1 RUNNING)
+----------------------------+----------+------------------------+---------+-------+--------+------------------+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Trial name                 | status   | loc                    |   gamma |    lr |   iter |   total time (s) |     ts |   reward |   episode_reward_max |   episode_reward_min |   episode_len_mean |
|----------------------------+----------+------------------------+---------+-------+--------+------------------+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------|
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00000 | RUNNING  | 192.168.252.130:361637 |     0   | 1     |     33 |          326.923 | 335920 |      nan |                  nan |                  nan |                nan |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00001 | PENDING  |                        |     0.2 | 1     |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00002 | PENDING  |                        |     0.4 | 1     |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00003 | PENDING  |                        |     0.6 | 1     |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00004 | PENDING  |                        |     0.8 | 1     |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00005 | PENDING  |                        |     1   | 1     |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00006 | PENDING  |                        |     0   | 0.1   |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00007 | PENDING  |                        |     0.2 | 0.1   |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00008 | PENDING  |                        |     0.4 | 0.1   |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00009 | PENDING  |                        |     0.6 | 0.1   |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00010 | PENDING  |                        |     0.8 | 0.1   |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00011 | PENDING  |                        |     1   | 0.1   |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00012 | PENDING  |                        |     0   | 0.01  |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00013 | PENDING  |                        |     0.2 | 0.01  |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00014 | PENDING  |                        |     0.4 | 0.01  |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00015 | PENDING  |                        |     0.6 | 0.01  |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00016 | PENDING  |                        |     0.8 | 0.01  |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00017 | PENDING  |                        |     1   | 0.01  |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00018 | PENDING  |                        |     0   | 0.001 |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
| A2C_TradingEnv_b9572_00019 | PENDING  |                        |     0.2 | 0.001 |        |                  |        |          |                      |                      |                    |
+----------------------------+----------+------------------------+---------+-------+--------+------------------+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
... 3 more trials not shown (3 PENDING)
```

So only one trial is running. I want to run multiple trials in parallel. When I want to run each trial on single CPU with:

```
analysis = tune.run(
    config=config,
    resources_per_trial = {"cpu": 1, "gpu": 0})
```

I have error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Resources for <class 'ray.rllib.agents.trainer_template.A2C'> have been automatically set to <ray.tune.utils.placement_groups.PlacementGroupFactory object at 0x7fe119c3f7c0> by its `default_resource_request()` method. Please clear the `resources_per_trial` option.
```

What should I do to have multiple parallel trial runs with 1 CPU each?

Comment: Ok, solved, had to define: `"num_workers" : 1,`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem now, but after I changed the `{ ...,  "num_workers": 1, ... }`, the trials are still one.

```
config_train = {
            "train_batch_size":   args.batch_size,
            "horizon":            args.horizon,
            "model":           { "fcnet_hiddens":  model_structure },
            "num_workers":        args.num_workers,
            "env_config":      { "generalize":     True,
                                 "run_valid":      False,
                                 "env":            args.env,
                                 "mid_range_init": args.mid_range_init },
            "framework":          args.framework,
            "episodes_per_batch": args.episodes_per_batch,
            "seed" :              args.seed,
            "lr" :                args.lr,
            "num_gpus":           4,
            "num_workers":        1
            }

trials = tune.run_experiments( { args.experiment: {
                                      "run":                  args.algo,
                                      "checkpoint_freq":      5,
                                      "keep_checkpoints_num": 1,
                                      "local_dir":            args.output_path,
                                      "env":                  env,
                                      "stop":              { "episode_reward_mean": -0.02 },
                                      "checkpoint_at_end":    True,
                                      "config":               config_train
                                      }
                                 }
                                 #progress_reporter=reporter
                               )
```

```
Resources requested: 2.0/40 CPUs, 4.0/4 GPUs, 0.0/73.24 GiB heap, 0.0/35.38 GiB objects (0.0/1.0 accelerator_type:GTX)
```

What should I do to have multiple parallel trials?

```
Number of trials: 1/1 (1 RUNNING)
```